# angular4-carousel not working with angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular5

I'm trying to use a slider in my angular 5 project (angular4-carousel) but its throwing error as I mentioned, I have tried using ngx-carousel but that one is also not working.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/angular4-carousel/index.ts
>       Module build failed: Error: D:\Workspace\ntwine\node_modules\angular4-carousel\index.ts is not
>   part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages
>   for details.
>           at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\Workspace\ntwine\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:649:23)
>           at plugin.done.then (D:\Workspace\ntwine\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>        @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 12:0-51
>        @ ./src/main.ts
>        @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

Why I got this error?

Comment: it isn't https://github.com/bonjurmrfirst/angular4-carousel/issues/33

Comment: Well, thanks for reading it but i'm new here and i was stuck very badly so i just posted thinking here might be someone who already used it..

Comment: ngx-carousel is working with angular5, i was missing one import file thats why it was creating the issue, till the time not sure about the angular4-carousel.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this and get this working by adding the following line to my **tsconfig.app.json** file under the **src** directory.

```
, //I added this section to fix the compile error
  "include": [
    "node_modules/angular4-carousel/index.ts"
  ]
```

This is my **edited** tsconfig.app.json file located under the src directory.

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
, //I added this section to fix the compile error, must pass the adject path of index.ts file
  "include": [
    "../node_modules/angular4-carousel/index.ts"
  ]
}
```